# How to target very specific symbols within a list value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have list `list = [1+3, 4, 3]`. I know that `list[0]` is equal to `1+3`, but how could I specifically print out the "+" in `list[0]`?

I tried of doing something like

```
plus = "+"

for plus in list:
    takeOut = list.remove(plus)
print(takeOut)
```

But the value returned is `None`

Allow me to add some context:
I want to make a program in which the user types in some equations, and the computer spits out results. If the user typed in `1+2 4-3` the computer would print `3 1`. 
Since the 0th value is equal to `1+2`, I thought maybe if I removed the "+", and then add up `1` and `2`, it would give me my desired results.

Here's my code file:

```
directions = print("Type in a equation")
numbers = [str(x) or int(x) or float(x) for x in input().split()]
print(numbers)

plus = '+'

for plus in numbers:
    takeOut = numbers.remove(plus)
print(takeOut)
```

Note that this is part of my first Python project I have ever done so if there is a better solution I would like to know it.

Comment: What is your expected result? Remove `+`?

Comment: `[1+3, 4, 3]` would just be `[4, 4, 3]` if they're integers.

Comment: In sounds like you're confusing the source code and the program state. The source code contains the "+" symbol, but when the program is executing, the the expression 1+3 is evaluated to 4 and stored in the list. There is no "+" in the list.

Comment: You're redefining `plus` in your for loop

Comment: Edited the question to provide some context. I should have provided it in the first place so I apologize.

Comment: The `for` loop is still redefining the variable `plus` each iteration...so for starters, don't do that.

Comment: I felt like my explanation didn't really deserve an entire answer, but..

In your example, 1+3 would be automatically evaluated unless you entered it in string format, like, "1+3"

Since it is being automatically evaluated, you could just print the list, and your results would be "[4, 4, 3]"

Comment: `1+3` is automatically converted to `4`.  The code doesn't remember the original equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistakenly confusing `for` loops with `if` statements. If you want to check if a certain thing is in a list, you should use the `if`
statement. This is how `for` loops are structured:

```py
for temporary_variable in iterable:
    # some code
    # for example if you loop through ["a", "b", "c"],
    # the temporary_variable will first held "a", then "b" on the next iteration and so on.
```

So this is how I have changed your code to match exactly what you want:

```
# Take user's equation as a string
user_eqn = input("Enter your equation: ")   # For example, 4+3 will be taken in as "4+3"

# Since it is a string, now it's possible to detect "+"
if "+" in user_eqn:
    eqn_nums = user_eqn.split("+")  # splitting on "+" will give you a list of numbers. For example, "4+3" will turn in to ["4", "3"]
    eqn_nums = [int(num) for num in eqn_nums]   # But they are still strings. So convert them to integers using a list comprehension
    print(sum(eqn_nums))  # Then use the sum function to calculate the sum of all the values in that list
```